# redux-toolkit delete all items when i try to delete one

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i'm migrating slowly to redux-toolkit

when i try to delete a single item from my store, the action works well because i send the right ID from the component, but i think that the way i send this id to the slice is incorrect so i'm not able to delete the right item from my store(it delete all the items)

component dispatch code:

```
 const handleDelete = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const del_id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id")

    dispatch(deleteComment(del_id))
  }
```

action & api call:

```
export const deleteComment = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch(deleteCommentsLoading())

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    }

    const { data } = await axios.delete(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}/publication/comment/delete/${id}`,
      config
    )

    dispatch(deleteCommentsSuccess({ commentId: id }))
    // i tried deleteCommentsSuccess(data); (id)... nothing work to send this id to the slice
 
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(
      deleteCommentsFail(
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message
      )
    )
  }
}
```

my slice:

```
 const commentSlice = createSlice({
 name: "comments",
  initialState: {
    comment: {},
    loading: false,
    error: false,
  },

... other reducers

// DELETE COMMENT
    deleteCommentsLoading: (state) => {
      state.loading = true
    },
    deleteCommentsFail: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload
      state.loading = false
    },
    deleteCommentsSuccess: (state, action) => {
      const { commentId } = action.payload
      state.comment.comments.filter((item) => item._id !== commentId)
      // i tried first when i send data or id to put action.payload.id nothing work
      state.loading = false
      state.error = false
    },
```

and this's my comments store slice, every item have his own "_id"

[image: this's my comments store slice, every item has his own "_id"]

Answer (score 0):

How is your backend. (comment)

Something like this? :

```
  const receita = await Recipe.findById(req.params.id)

  if (receita) {
    await receita.remove()
    res.json({ message: 'Receita removed' })
  } else {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('Receita not found')
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes the same logic:
```
const DeleteComment = await Comment.findOneAndDelete({_id: id, user:userId });
 return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "comment was deleted succesfully" });
```
and this part works well it delete the specific comment
(should i send the id with the success API response ?)
there's no way to catch the id i used in the front ?(see my action creator code)

Answer (score 0):

`state.comment.comments.filter((item) => item._id !== commentId)` will just return a filtered copy of the array,but not actually modify anything.

You have to do

```js
state.comment.comments = state.comment.comments.filter((item) => item._id !== commentId)
```

Comment: thank you, actually i've already tried this one before posting the problem,
everytime i got all my comments slice deleted, (then i should to re(getComments) to get my actual comments (without the specific item(_id) deleted because this API call works well, 
but in the front and redux side i'm not even sure that i'm sending correctly the id from component > slice or action > slice to filter the array